# Connect to MySql Remote Server | Access Denied

Tags: mysql, laravel, remote-server

My *Laravel* Project Files Hosted in **example.in/projects/projectName**
And the Database is on **example.com**

What I did
On **`example.com`** Added Access Host IP of `example.in` on Remote MySql Option.
On my Configuration(`.env`) File which is hosted on `example.in`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=IPofExample.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sampleDatabase
DB_USERNAME=sampleUsername
DB_PASSWORD=samplePassword
```

Now When I try to fetch record from database. It shows me the following error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ashutoshvibgyor'@'sg2plcpnl0032.prod.sin2.secureserver.net' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `case_studies`)"
```

Although I give all privileges to user when I Created One.
I crawled through stackoverflow and google but didn't get any helpful answer.

> I'm using **shared hosting**

Screenshot of my **`phpmyadmin`** page
[image]

Comment: could it be that while you allow remote connection to your mysql server from that ip, the sampleUser only has localhost permissions?

Comment: Don't know about that. Do you have any reference to that.. @Quezler

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin or cli mysql?

Comment: Mysql is a bit retarded in that it requires the same user to be create twice,once with localhost and once with % so it can be accessed from outside. `CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE.* TO 'username'@'%';` Im guessing you have only the first user.

Comment: I'm using **phpmyadmin** @Quezler

Comment: Allright, @AshutoshSharma, the bellow should work :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow a mysql user to connect from a non-localhost ip in phpmyadmin:

(assuming mysql is already `port forwarded/etc`)

Go to `User accounts` > click `edit privileges` on your user > switch the oval tab at the top to `login information` > edit the host field to either your your ipv4 of your office/home/etc, or `%`, then press go in the bottom right corner.

Comment: there is no option for `login information` or host edit

Comment: could you add a screenshot of your phpmyadmin page? (of course redact sensitive information)